# Segment fault when i trying to write Dictionary in C code

Tags: segmentation-fault

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct node {
    char data [ 20 ];
    char m [ 20 ];
    int mcount;
    struct node * next;
};

struct node * dic [26];

void add(char *);
int search(char *);
void show();
void deldic();

void main() {
    char word [ 20 ], ch;
    int i;



    while (1) {

        printf("\n\t\tDictionary\n");
        printf("\n\t\t1.Add Word.\n");
        printf("\t\t2.Search Word.\n");
        printf("\t\t3.Show Dictionary.\n");
        printf("\t\t4.Update.\n");
        printf("\t\t0.Exit.");
        printf("\n\n\t\tYour Choice ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);

        switch (ch) {
            case 1:

                printf("\nEnter any word : ");
                fpurge(stdin);
                gets(word);
                add(word);

                break;

            case 2:

                printf("\nEnter the word to search : ");
                fpurge(stdin);
                gets(word);
                i = search(word);
                if (!i)
                    printf("Word does not exists.");


                break;

            case 3:

                show();


                break;

            case 4:
                printf("\nEnter any word to update: ");
                fpurge(stdin);
                gets(word);
                update(word);
                break;

            default:

                printf("\nWrong Choice");
        }
    }
}

void add(char * str) {
    int i, j = toupper(str [ 0 ]) - 65;
    // 
    struct node * r, * temp = dic [ j ], * crawler;
    char mean [ 20 ];

    i = search(str);
    if (i) {
        printf("\nWord already exists.");

        return;
    }
    crawler = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof ( struct node));
    strcpy(crawler -> data, str);
    crawler -> next = NULL;
    printf("\n\nEnter the meaning(s) : ");
    gets(mean);
    strcpy(crawler -> m, mean);
    crawler -> mcount = i;
    if (dic [ j ] == NULL || strcmp(dic [ j ] -> data, str) > 0) {
        r = dic [ j ];
        dic [ j ] = crawler;
        crawler -> next = r;
        return;
    } else {
        while (temp != NULL) {
            if ((strcmp(temp -> data, str) < 0) && ((strcmp(temp -> next -> data, str) > 0) || temp -> next == NULL)) {
                crawler -> next = temp -> next;
                temp -> next = crawler;
                return;
            }
            temp = temp -> next;
        }
    }
}

int search(char *str) {
    struct node *n;
    char temp1 [ 20 ];
    char temp2 [ 20 ];
    int i;

    n = dic [ toupper(str [ 0 ]) - 65 ];
    strcpy(temp2, str);
    strupr(temp2);

    while (n != NULL) {
        strcpy(temp1, n -> data);

        if (strcmp(strupr(temp1), temp2) == 0) {
            printf("\n%s\t\t%s", n -> data, n -> m);
            for (i = 1; i < n -> mcount; i++)
                printf("\n\t\t%s", n -> m);
            return 1;
        }
        n = n -> next;
    }
    return 0;
}

int update(char* str) {
    struct node *n;
    char temp1 [ 20 ];
    char temp2 [ 20 ];
    char mean [ 20];

    n = dic [ toupper(str [ 0 ]) - 65 ];
    strcpy(temp2, str);
    strupr(temp2);

    while (n != NULL) {
        strcpy(temp1, n -> data);

        if (strcmp(strupr(temp1), temp2) == 0) {
            printf("\n\nEnter the meaning(s) : ");
            gets(mean);
            strcpy(n -> m, mean);
            return 1;
        }
        n = n -> next;
    }
    return 0;
}
// print the dictionary
void show() {
    struct node *n;
    int i, j;

    printf("Word\t\tMeaning\n");
    for (i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
        printf("-");


    for (i = 0; i <= 25; i++) {
        n = dic [ i ];
        while (n != NULL) {
            printf("\n%s\t\t%s", n -> data, n -> m);
            for (j = 1; j < n -> mcount; j++)
                printf("\n\t\t%s", n -> m);
            n = n -> next;
        }
    }
}
//function to free pointer.
void deldic() {
    struct node *n, *t;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 25; i++) {
        n = dic [ i ];
        while (n != NULL) {
            t = n -> next;
            free(n);
            n = t;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using linked list to write this program.But when i ran and enter two word :"go" and "goes" with their meaning.The error Segmentation fault show up.
I had spent 1 hours to it.Difficult to fix that bug.
I need some advice.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: do you have access to gdb on your machine? it can tell you exact line segfault is happening on then go from there

Comment: It would help if you narrow it down to the function where it occurred, Additionally, if you are on Linux you may want to use valgrind.

Comment: @brad It's happening at gets(mean) when i enter "goes" and its meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition

```
(strcmp(temp->next->data, str) > 0) || temp->next == NULL
```

is either buggy or superfluous. If `temp->next` can be null,  `temp->next->data` is an error. If it can't, the test is not needed. Perhaps you wanted:

```
temp->next == NULL || (strcmp(temp->next->data, str) > 0)
```